# How to destroy view created in an onClickListener method?

Tags: android, kotlin, expandablelistview

(I'm very new to Kotlin and programming in general, so I apologize if this has an obvious solution I couldn't figure out.)

I'm trying to create an ExpandableListView in which the children can also be expanded and collapsed. I've managed to set up an onChildClickListener that inflates the necessary layout but I can't figure out a way to destroy or remove said layout when the child is clicked again.

Here's the code:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val dataset: List<Medication> = MedicationsListData().loadMedicationsList()
    val medicationsListView: ExpandableListView = view.findViewById(R.id.medications_list_view)

    medicationsListView.setAdapter(MedicationsListAdapter(requireContext(), dataset))
    medicationsListView.setOnChildClickListener { _, v, groupPosition, childPosition, _ ->
        //get data for correct item
        val tempKey = (dataset.distinctBy { it.groupName })[groupPosition].groupName
        val clickedItem = dataset.filter { it.groupName == tempKey }[childPosition]

        //inflate or destroy medication_item_content
        var contentView: View? = null
        if (contentView == null) {
            val layoutInflater =
                this.requireContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.medication_item_content,
                v.findViewById(R.id.content_view_holder),
                true
            )
        } else contentView!!.visibility = View.GONE

        //populate view with data
        false
    }
```

I get an error if I move the contentView variable outside the onChildClickListener method:

```
Added variable(s) does not support value initialization: Adding field object com.example.quickref.uicontrollers.MedicationsFragment.contentView
```

Adding a simple Boolean variable wouldn't work either since there's multiple children each with the same method.

I guess an alternative would be to set the children as ExpandableListViews as well, but it seems that this would require a huge amount of seemingly unnecessary code, because the structure of the expandable/collapsible content is the same and right now I can fill the strings from one data class.

Thanks!

Comment: I actually did that about 2 years ago. I used ExpandableListView as a child for ExpandableListView.  It is messy but it does the job. Just keep in mind that you'll have to pay attention to the height of your layout each time the child is pressed to expand its view. If I find an example of this I'll send you. Not sure if this is the best way to go with it, maybe using dialogs when a child is clicked is a better option to show your data and implement your reaction to that event.

Comment: Thanks! Agreed, this would be messy and if possible I'd like to avoid that solution. A dialog doesn't meet my requirements in this situation because I need the ability to have multiple children with their respective views expanded at the same time.

Comment: Then I guess your only option is to go with it. Just use ExpandableListView as Child and another adapter for it. It's not that hard to implement that, I did when I was only a few months into android development.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView
?
It is more complex version of list with possibility to make expandable items.

Comment: Thanks! This is my backup plan at the moment. However, it seems like this would require lots of duplicate data and I'm trying to avoid this solution if possible.

Comment: Oh.. I am sorry. I didn't realized it is one expandable inside the other one. Stupid me xD

Comment: About this;"onChildClickListener that inflates the necessary layout but I can't figure out a way to destroy or remove said layout when the child is clicked again." Have you tried to just change visibility to GONE and again to Visible?

Comment: Tried it, sort of. Point is, since I cannot initialize this variable outside the same method, it will only ever be "null" before the if/else block, so the else branch will never run. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Can't you inflate any list or linearlayout in MedicationsListAdapter and on click on the item just change the visibility of the child part?

Comment: Anyway - I don't think that ExpandableListView inside ExpandableListView is horrible way to do that. Or maybe I can't see the redundation you are talking about.